# How to write get value in php on same page

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i did a code i php but it is not working i dont know why

Here is my code

**update.php**

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("helixcrm",$link);
$q="select * from clientreg";
$ros=mysql_query($q);
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
    {
        if($i%2==0)
            $classname="evenRow";
        else
            $classname="oddRow";
        ?>

        <tr class="<?php echo $classname;?>">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }?>

<?php
$focus = array();
$rowCount = count($_Post["users"]);
echo $rowCount;
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientreg WHERE Id='" . $_POST["users"][$i] . "'");
    $row[$i]= mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //echo $row[$i]['interest'];
    $focus = explode(',', $row[$i]['interest']);
    $check = implode(',' , $focus);

    // echo $check;
    echo $row[$i]['id'];
}

?>

<form>
</form>
```

Here i this code   **$rowCount = count($_Post["users"]);** not working here but if i write this on another php page it works

Where i am wrong

how can  i achieve my output

any help will be appreciated

Comment: The variable is `$_POST`, not `$_Post`.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @Barmar i did not understand what did you said

Comment: `$_Post["users"]` should be `$_POST["users"]`. PHP variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: @Barmar i changed variable still not working

Comment: `$_POST` isn't filled in until the user submits a form. You're running that code even when you're just displaying the form initially, not checking whether the form has been submitted.

Comment: @Barmar could u write some code  please

Comment: Where is the `<form>` in your page?

Comment: @Barmar i updated form in my above code

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this

```
    <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $example = $_POST['example'];
    $example2 = $_POST['example2'];
    echo $example . " " . $example2;
  }
  ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
     Example value: <input name="example" type="text" />
     Example value 2: <input name="example2" type="text" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>
```